# Showing Bessel Function solves the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Part of my assignment is to show that

$$
J(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot (t/2)^{2n}}{(n!)^2}
$$
solves the ODE
$$
t\cdot J''(t) + J'(t) + t\cdot J(t) = 0.
$$
By differentiating within the radius of convergence and then substitution I'm left with a very long solution that I doesn't look like it will go to zero. I was wondering if there were any short cuts rather than brute force substitution.

Comment: Collect all the multipliers of $t^n$ for each $n$.  All of these coefficients should turn out to be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$t\cdot J''(t) + J'(t) + t\cdot J(t) = 0.$$
$$t^2\cdot J''(t) + tJ'(t) + t^2\cdot J(t) = 0.$$
So we have :
$$t^2J(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot (t)^{2(n+1)}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}$$
$$tJ'(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2n\frac{(-1)^n\cdot (t)^{2n}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}$$
$$t^2J''(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2n(2n-1)\frac{(-1)^n\cdot (t)^{2n}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}$$

---

You need to rewrite properly the three series. note that the second and third serie reduces to:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4n^2\frac{(-1)^n\cdot (t)^{2n}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot (t)^{2(n+1)}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}=0$$
Change the indice of the second sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4n^2\frac{(-1)^{n}\cdot (t)^{2n}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}-\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m\cdot (t)^{2m}}{((m-1)!)^22^{2(m-1)}}=0$$ 
The first serie starts at $n=1$ because the first term is zero:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4n^2\frac{(-1)^n\cdot (t)^{2n}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}-\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m4m^2(t)^{2m}}{(m!)^22^{2m}}=0$$
It's zero. Both series are the same with opposite sign.